# Redirect to external URL from express.js does not work

Tags: facebook, redirect, express

I am working on getting the Facebook "Authentication within a Canvas Page" working,  [as described here for PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas/). I finally got the base64_decode stuff working but I do fail on redirecting the user to the URL described in Section 2a. I tried response.redirect(url) as well as response.setHeader('Location', url) and other options I found on SO, but none of these worked :/

If I visit the URL directly through the browser, everything seems to work as expected. If I redirect to an URL on the same domain, it works too. Maybe I am missing something basic? Are redirects to external domains possible? What is the correct way to get this done?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: I just figured out that redirecting to pages like http://heise.de or http://orf.at works, but not for http://www.google.com or http://www.facebook.com. I have no clue what is going on here :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just figured out that redirecting to pages like `http://heise.de` or `http://orf.at` works, but not for `http://www.google.com` or `http://www.facebook.com`. I have no clue what is going on here :/

The latter ones are sending an `X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header, which tells the client whether the page wants to be displayed in (i)frames or not.

Google sends the value `SAMEORIGIN`, which means only pages from the domain google.com are allowed to display other pages from google.com in (i)frames, and Facebook sends `DENY`, meaning the page is never allowed to be displayed in any kind of frame, no matter where.

Answer (score 0):

As I was not able to solve the problem, I wanted to share the workaround I used with you. 
The problem seems to be, that Facebook includes the page in an iframe and thus only allows to redirect using window.top.location, which obviously cannot be done from server-side. I used a workaround now and render a jade view which does nothing but window.top.location = url. Not very pretty, but it works. Why some pages work and others don't is still a question to me.